# How to implement payments without ejecting from Expo (react-native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, payment

I need to be able to do payments in the app. But I would also like to do it without Ejecting from Expo because of Expo client app for testing and mainly because of build helpers for Android and iOS.

My thought was to accept cards using some gateway and Webview and maybe accept GooglePay and ApplePay by Link to normal Google browser and than webPayments API or so. Do any of you have better idea, have you dealt with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the only way i could do it is by creating a webpage and use `react-native-webview` this way if you don't want to eject your expo project

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

...
...

    <WebView
         source={{ uri: "https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout" }}
         cacheEnabled={false}
    />
```

[image: Payment in app]